# display the array values-ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to display the values in datatable. How to retrieve the object value in ajax success function..
[image: ajax]

AJAX

```
  $(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "#submits", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

    var password = $("#password").val();
    alert(password);
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "db/add.php",
     data: "password="+password,
     success: function(results){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + results );

        var obj = JSON.parse(results);
        }
});

    e.preventDefault();

});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this -

```
$("#submits").bind("click", function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        cache : false,
        url : "db/add.php",
        data : "password="+password,
        success : function(results) {
            alert("Data Saved: "+results);
                var userInfo = JSON.parse(results);

                //Output the data to an HTML element - example...
                $(".user-name").html(userInfo.patient_name);

            }else{
                console.log('No user info found');
            }
        },
        error : function(a,b,c) {
            console.log('There was an error getting user info.');
        }
    });
});

//HTML element for data
<p class="user-name"></p>
```

I've added an HTML element you can simply output the data to. Not sure how you'd like the data to be output but this is simply an example.

Just some quick notes on your code from your original post -

- You must set the dataType to json when working with/parsing json. See [Documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- Once you assign your data to a variable, you need to access that data by declaring the variable and then the data name, such as `obj.patient_name`.

I've done the best I can to help.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$(results.patient_password).each(function(i,v){
   console.log(v.id);
});
```

Comment: i am getting the value as undefined

Comment: No output is not being displayed

Answer (score -1):

use data-type:json,

in your jquery

Comment: This does **not** answer the question in a useful way. _why_ do you believe this is the answer? _how_ does it work? Simply telling someone to _change their code_ without any context or meaning does not help them learn what they did wrong.